# Object obect error on jquery ajax request on dropdown change?

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net, ajax

I'm using jquery ajax on dropdown change function.The problem is that even before hitting the url mentioned in the ajax request I'm getting `Object object error`.

The ajax request is as follows

```
 $("#locationList").change(function () {
             var locationNo = document.getElementById('<%=locationList.ClientID%>').value;
             $.ajax({
                 url: "HealthReport.aspx/GetCashsafes",
                 data: "{ 'Location': '" + locationNo + "'}",
                 type: "POST",
                 dataType: "json",
                 contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                 success: function (data) {
                     alert("Success");
                     response($.each(data.d, function (key, value) {                        
                     $("#CashSafeList").append($("<option></option>").val(value.CashsafeId).html(value.CashsafeDisplaySerialNo));
                     }));
                 },
                 error: function (result) {
                     alert(result);
                     $("#CashSafeList").append($("<option></option>").val("-1").html("Select one"));
                 }
             });
         });
```

The server side code is as follows

```
 [WebMethod]       
    public static string GetCashsafes(string Location)
    {
        Decimal userId = (Decimal)AMSECSessionData.userId;
        List<Cashsafe> lstCashSafe = DropDown.getCashSafeListLocationwise(userId, Convert.ToDecimal(Location));
        List<CashSafeSelect> lstCashSafeSelect = new List<CashSafeSelect>();
        lstCashSafeSelect = lstCashSafe.Select(item => new CashSafeSelect()
        {
            CashsafeId=(decimal)item.CashsafeId,
            CashsafeSerialNo=item.CashsafeSerialNo.ToString()

        }).Distinct().ToList();
        System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer jSearializer =
              new System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer();
        string sjson=jSearializer.Serialize(lstCashSafeSelect);
        return sjson;     
    }
```

I've checked the `string sjson` and the data is returning correctly in json format.

Since the error is showing even before the url is hit,i'm confused on how to proceed further.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: try to change your .aspx page context.Response.ContentType = "application/json";

Comment: you also check your page content type through webpage info. For that you have to open .aspx page on browser, right click on page and select "View Page Info".

Comment: tried ur method but still getting the same error.I also checked the page info,the result is as follows `Type=Text/Html;Encoding=UTF-8`

Comment: You are getting error because still you page content type is "text/HTML" and in your AJAX call you have mentioned datatype " 'json'. Either you have to change your .aspx content type or ajax call datatype.

Comment: How can i change .aspx content type?Any piece of code will be helpful.

Comment: try this context.Response.ContentType = "application/json"

Comment: try to set dataType : 'html', instead of dataType: "json", in your ajax call without change .aspx page content type.

Comment: tried it but still getting the error.The modified code is as follows ` dataType: "html",
  contentType: "application/json; charset=UTF-8"`

Answer (score 0):

Change the `data` like this

```
data: JSON.stringify({ 'Location':  locationNo }),
```

Then your code will look like

```
$("#locationList").change(function () {
         var locationNo = document.getElementById('<%=locationList.ClientID%>').value;
         $.ajax({
             url: "HealthReport.aspx/GetCashsafes",
             data: JSON.stringify({ 'Location':  locationNo }),
             type: "POST",
             dataType: "json",
             contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
             success: function (data) {
                 alert("Success");
                 response($.each(data.d, function (key, value) {                        
                 $("#CashSafeList").append($("<option></option>").val(value.CashsafeId).html(value.CashsafeDisplaySerialNo));
                 }));
             },
             error: function (result) {
                 alert(result);
                 $("#CashSafeList").append($("<option></option>").val("-1").html("Select one"));
             }
         });
     });
```

**Edit**

Since your `dataType` is json, you should return `json`, not `string`. Change your server side code like this,

```
[WebMethod]       
public static List<CashSafeSelect> GetCashsafes(string Location)
{
    Decimal userId = (Decimal)AMSECSessionData.userId;
    List<Cashsafe> lstCashSafe = DropDown.getCashSafeListLocationwise(userId, Convert.ToDecimal(Location));
    List<CashSafeSelect> lstCashSafeSelect = new List<CashSafeSelect>();
    lstCashSafeSelect = lstCashSafe.Select(item => new CashSafeSelect()
    {
        CashsafeId=(decimal)item.CashsafeId,
        CashsafeSerialNo=item.CashsafeSerialNo.ToString()

    }).Distinct().ToList();

    return lstCashSafeSelect;     
}
```

You dont have to serialize those lists

Comment: Any explanation why the OP should do that? He already stated _I've checked the string sjson and the data is returning correctly in json format._

Comment: But he said that "The problem is that even before hitting the url mentioned in the ajax request I'm getting Object object error". It may be because the mismatch in contentType

Comment: Tried the code as above but still getting the error.

Comment: are you getting success alert?

Comment: No getting [Obect object] error.Im using MVC application and in that I've created aspx pages(for doing crystal reports). Any issues with that ?

Comment: Thankyou for you reply.I edited the code as yours but still getting the error.When i checked  page content type it is `text/HTML`. In my AJAX call i have mentioned datatype as `json`.I think the error may be due to this conflict.Got any idea of how to proceed?

Comment: can you remove dataType and contentType from your ajax

Comment: Sorry mate removed it but still getting the error.And the url is not getting hit.

Comment: so if you dont remove those, will the ajax hit on the function in server?

Comment: yes function in the server will get hit,but at the same time the error will popup.

Comment: Where?? Is the error pop up at server?? Or in ajax call??

Comment: In ajax call inside the error function, i have called an alert.This will popup.Pls see the above posted ajax call for reference.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/53955/discussion-between-sparaby-and-anoop-joshi)

Answer (score 0):

Issue solved,Thanks to every one who replied especially @Anoop.

Issue was that I've set `Autopostback=true` for the dropdown where the ajax call is made.I've removed the `autopostback` property of the dropdown and now the code is working fine.

I wonder how a fresh day,clear mind helps to solve the issues.